# Is a typical register rising edge or falling edge?

Tags: clock, register

I'm using Logisim to build a 1-bit CPU. However, I am having issues with timing the registers up with the clock. In a CPU, should registers be rising edge or falling edge? Or, could they be something else, like active HIGH or LOW?

Comment: that question makes little sense, and isn't even specific to a CPU: in any clocked logic circuit, you can make your registers be rising, falling, both edges-active; high or low active rarely makes sense for registers.

Comment: It depends on the particular requirements of your design. Can you show it to us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you just want to design/model/simulate a basic CPU, right?

If that's the case, I would follow the KIS (Keep It Simple) principle, and make all the registers positive edge triggered.

Comment: Yeah, actually, my ALU was the problem. I used a JK flipflop to store the INV instruction, and i guess it backfired on me.

Comment: you could also make all the registers negative edge triggered

Comment: @jsotola, one could - but that's by far the minority case. The OP should use positive edge clocking, following the vast majority convention. Note should, not must.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **yes**. Registers should be rising edge or falling edge. Or, they could be level-sensitive latches with an active-high enable or an active-low enable. The design of a CPU is highly optimized and customized for the particular fabrication technology that will be used, the desired performance characteristics, and power consumption goals.

I'm making this an answer only so that the question will officially have an answer.

Comment: Okay, so they can be either?

Comment: For more information, re-read the answer, @NipDip.

Comment: @NipDip Do you have a textbook you can reference? Usually you start by learning how registers work before trying to build a whole CPU.

Comment: I know the basics but its hard to sync it with the clock.

Comment: @NipDip it's really not clear what you mean with "it's hard to sync with the clock"; it really is not, unless you're basically misunderstanding how clocked circuits work, and that's impossible to remedy with the lack of information on what you're actually doing, currently.

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule but, answering for clocked digital logic circuits rather than specifically a CPU...

Rising-edge clocked D-type Flip-Flops (DFFs) are by far the most common type you will find.

It is not convenient to use level-triggered logic - what you allude to as 'active HIGH or LOW'. This would mean using transparent latches and that is an impractical technology to make any digital circuit with feedback, such as a counter.

For the record, edge-triggered registers do in fact consist of two transparent latches in series: one in 'hold' when clock is high, the other in 'hold' when clock is low. But the end result is an edge-triggered register.

Comment: Transparent latches have been commonly used in CPUs, and the technology is not at all impractical. You just need to start with a 2-phase, non-overlapping clock generator. The design is certainly more difficult, but the result is less silicon so less unit cost.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, in ASICs, two transparent latches are used - to make a single edge-triggered flip-flop. That is not what I describe under the banner 'level-triggered logic'. Single transparent latches are not used as registers, except in very rare cases.

Comment: In full-custom processor design, transparent latches are used in designs that employ 2-phase or 4-phase clocking. Transparent latches are most certainly used as registers. You may say "rare cases" but I'm talking about real processor design, not ASICs or FPGAs.